# Difficulty in calculating moment of inertia of ring about an axis perpendicular to ring using integration[Solved]

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, classical-mechanics

[image]

I want to calculate moment of inertia of uniform ring about an axis which is **${\large perpendicular}$** to the surface of ring and passing through $F$ using integration.

By parallel axis theorem, Moment of inertia of ring about this axis  is $2MR^2$.

Let radius and mass of Ring be $R$ and $m$ respectively

Let $DE$ be the differential element of length $dx$ and mass $dm$. Let $\angle AFE$ be $\theta$ and $\angle EFD$ be $d\theta$. Also Let $EF=FD=x$

$$I=\int x^2 dm$$ , where $x$ represents perpendicular distance from axis of rotation.

As $$dm=\frac{m}{2\pi R}dx$$

$$\implies I=\frac{m}{2\pi R}\int x^2 dx$$

As $AF=AE=R$, From cosine law we have $cos\theta=\frac{x}{2R}$. Also $dx=x d\theta$.

$$I=\frac{m}{2\pi R}\int_{0}^{2\pi} 4R^2cos^2\theta(2Rcos\theta) d\theta$$

$$\ \implies I=\frac{4mR^2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}cos^3 \theta d\theta$$

This gives $I=0$ but this is wrong as answer is $2mR^2$. I wasn't able to find mistake in calculation for moment of inertia. Initially I thought that problem is with limits of integrals but then I realise that even if limits are wrong that $\pi$ in denominator won't cancel which still makes our result wrong.

**Note:- This question is now solved. The mistake lies in limits of integral. Angle should have been measured from centre of Ring.**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: $dm\ne\frac m{2\pi}dx$

Comment: @Jihai Zhu We are given that ring is uniform(Constant Areal density or $\sigma$).

Comment: Your diagram doesn't match you description:
 - I suppose angle AFE is theta, not  AFB
 - you say EF=x but that is not the perpendicular distance from the axis

Comment: @Blitzer Can you elaborate

Comment: @user1055 $dx$ is not the length of the differential element.

Comment: That is length of $DE$ and I have considered It differential element

Comment: @Blitzer Axis $BC$ is perpendicular to plane of Ring(As given in description of question)

Comment: @user1055 DE is not perpendicular to DF. $DE=\frac{dx}{cos\angle DEF}$

Comment: @Jihai Zhu As said above $EF=DF=x$(since $dx\to 0$) So we can say that $dx=xd\theta$

Comment: @user1055 The only point is that DE is not perpendicular to DF, so that $ \DE\ne dx$.

Comment: @Jihai Zhu I haven't said $DE \perp DF$ and nor they are, Point $E$and $F$ are just very close to each other.If you are facing difficulty then you can assume a circle with centre at $F$ and $DE$ as arc of that circle with $EF$and $DF$ as Radius.Also Differential element can be of any shape not just a straight line.